# Getting right side numbers of my Id

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns IDs.

```
SELECT Id from MyTable;
```

The result is something like this:

```
2400044
243000178
12300044
```

Now I would like to get only numbers on the right side of 000 (three zeros).

So:

```
44
178
44
```

Comment: Use `RIGHT` function

Comment: What is supposed to happen for this: '200030004' ?

Comment: What if there is no '000'?  Can the target number be longer than 3.  Is ID an integer or character?

Comment: Can you add more data to the question as suggested by others to test the code against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the original number when no matches on 000 is found, it will find the first occurance of 000 and return the number after that:

```
DECLARE @t table(a int)
INSERT @t
values(2400044),(243000178),(12300044),(10002000)

SELECT a%(power(10,len(a)-charindex('000',a)))
FROM @t
```

This require that the number is an actual integer or bigint. Float or varchar  with characters which isn't numeric(0-9) will fail

Comment: It returns the number if no match on 000 is found.  May be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Paparazzi you are right, I changed my script from an earlier version. Corrected the comment

Answer (score 1):

Solution using CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING()

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Id], CHARINDEX('000', [Id])+3, LEN([Id]))
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Does not work if Id is and integer.  But can cast to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING` AND `CHARINDEX` Function as below:

```
DECLARE @myNumber VARCHAR(50)='2400057744'
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@myNumber),0,CHARINDEX('000',REVERSE(@myNumber))))
```

Output:

```
2400044 to 44
243000178 to 178
12300044 to 44
200030004 to 4
```

In table form

```
SELECT a Raw, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(a), 0, CHARINDEX('000', REVERSE(a)))) Number 
from ( values (2400044), (243000178), (12300045), (2430001789), (2430033), (20003000101) 
     ) k(a)
```

Comment: output for 20003000101?

Comment: it will return 101

Answer (score 0):

Use `patindex()` with `substring()` function to get the right side value

```
select 
      substring(Id, patindex('%[0][0][0]%', Id)+3, len(Id)) Id
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is an INT or BIGINT, with a return of 5 digits or less:

```
create table #MyTable (Id int)

Insert Into #MyTable Values (2400044), (243000178), (12300044)

select id%100000 from #MyTable
```

IF it is a string:

```
Select Cast(Cast(id as bigint)%100000 as varchar(10)) from #MyTable
```

Comment: what will happen if the number is 100012345

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks. I hadn't anticipated 5 figures. I have adjusted for that by changing 1000 to 100000.

Comment: but this will not be generic.. :)

Comment: 1000123456 will return 23456. Seems kind of arbitrary

Comment: @PawanKumar It works for 5 digits or less. If more are required, it won't work. If 5 digits suffice, it is an efficient solution.

Comment: What if 000 is not present at all?

Comment: @plaidDK "Must be sufficient"?  Your logic is different from mine.

Comment: The OP has not declared what datatype 'Id' is. A mathematical solution will be far quicker. The boundaries have not been specified; so far we just have sample data. It is likely that this type of solution will be applicable. It can most likely be adjusted, if not. Work with me, guys!

Comment: @plaidDK That is an "attack".  Your sense of language is different from mine.